# GCP - cannot write back to UDP packet

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, udp, google-compute-engine

I try to run UDP server on compute engine. I have a Docker image running go program very similar to this (https://github.com/felipejfc/go-udp-echo-server/blob/master/main.go)
I run it in compute engine on container optimized OS and I configure network via load balancer.

loadbalancer -> managed instance groups

When I ssh into compute engine instance and send packet, it works as expected

```
nc -u localhost 10001
# this echos!
```

However when I send UDP packet from my machine with

```
nc -u <loadbalancer_ip> 10001
```

I can see UDP packet reaches to my server (I add log to my program just after I do `ServerConn.WriteTo`), however I don't get any response from the server. What could be the reason for this?

EDIT:
when I netcat to loadbalancer IP form the box it self, it echos..

```
nc -u <loadbalancer_ip> 10001
# this echos from VM, but not from my local machine..
```

Comment: Is the service listening on that ip? Perhaps try connecting to the IP instead of localhost on the server itself.

Comment: interestingly it worked from VM... updated post above

Answer (score 0):

This was because I was binding to 0.0.0.0 while request is coming to my loadbalancer IP. I had to bind to loadbalancer IP - https://serverfault.com/questions/768681/udp-server-behind-gcloud-load-balancer-receive-ok-reply-fails